# How To configure apache solr 9.0.0 dataimport handler

Tags: solr9

I am not getting correct way of configure dataimport handler.
i want to import mysql AND SQL server dataimport in solr.

Want to import mysql database in solr version.
or migrate solr version 8 to 9.

I was configure dataimport handler old way but this not work i mean after configuration core is not load.

Comment: We need some details, share your config with us, please

Comment: I Just install.My OS ubuntu currently i am using solr version 8 and i want set new solr of letest version 9.Latest solr version is depricated dataimport handler so How can i import data in solr using database connection. Plese share any one solution Here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i searching New solution on those problem's in Linux based system.

firstly you set your Apache solr and configure it.

and you simply Create a `.sh` file and enter following content in this file.

`nano FILE_NAME`

```bash
    #!/bin/bash
    
    # MySQL Database Configuration
    MYSQL_HOST="DATABASE_IP"
    MYSQL_USER="USER"
    MYSQL_PASSWORD="Password"
    MYSQL_DATABASE="pulse"
    LAST_INDEX_TIME_FILE="$HOME/.dataimport.properties"
    
    # Solr Configuration
    SOLR_URL="http://localhost:YOUR_SOLR_PORT/solr"
    COLLECTION_NAME="kaldin"
    SOLR_POST_TOOL="/opt/solr/bin/post"  # Replace with your Solr bin/post tool path
    
    # Get the last index time from a file
    LAST_INDEX_TIME=$(cat $LAST_INDEX_TIME_FILE)
    
    # MySQL query to retrieve data modified since the last index time
    MYSQL_QUERY="SELECT client_id, 
                    client_siffix, client_first_name, client_middle_name, client_last_name, client_email, client_phone_1, client_phone_2,
                    fk_client_enum_id, client_u_id, fk_company_id, 
                    client_status, client_is_active, client_modified_date, fk_client_team_id, fk_client_team_id1 FROM client;" > '$LAST_INDEX_TIME'
    
    # Execute the MySQL query and transform data if needed
    MYSQL_OUTPUT=$(mysql -h$MYSQL_HOST -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE -e "$MYSQL_QUERY")
    
    # Prepare the data for Solr (e.g., convert to JSON)
    # Modify this part based on your data format and requirements
    
    # Use Solr's post tool to send the data to Solr
    echo "$MYSQL_OUTPUT" | $SOLR_POST_TOOL -c $COLLECTION_NAME -d
    
    # Record the current time as the last index time
    date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" > $LAST_INDEX_TIME_FILE
```

after that give this file full permission using `chmod`
`chmod 777 FILE_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use some contributors' packages like https://github.com/SearchScale/dataimporthandler. This is a good one by the way, all the installation and usage instructions are in the README of the repo.

This was well explained in this topic: [What is going to replace the DataImportHandler in Solr 9.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131030/what-is-going-to-replace-the-dataimporthandler-in-solr-9-0)

Comment: I am using this but at a time this jar file getting data in database full i want to import  data in slow and continuasly only updated data in database